# Google charts; arrayToDataTable, how to specify column type?

Tags: php, json, google-visualization

In google charts we can use `var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();` and be able to specify the column type like `date` or `number` etc..

Like in this example:

```
$dataTable = array (
    'cols' => array (
        array('type' => 'date', 'label' => 'Date'),
        array('type' => 'number', 'label' => 'Some data'),
        array('type' => 'number', 'label' => 'Other data')
    ),
    'rows' => array()
);
```

How can I achieve the same with `var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable();` from data returned from PHP through json_encode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google.visualization.arraytodatatable) you can do the following:

> The column data types are determined automatically by the data provided. Column data types can also be specified using the object literal notation in the first row (the column header row) of the array (i.e. {label: 'Start Date', type: 'date'}).

So your dataarray would be something like:

```
var dataArray = [
                 [{label:'Date', type:'date'},
                  {label:'Some data', type:'number'}, 
                  {label:'Other data', type:'number'}],
                 [
                  [date,number,number],
                  [more rows]
                ]
```

Comment: Thanks.. it works. Strange though I did the same before and didn't work.. hmm